# Как оптимально осуществить фильтрацию списка объектов?

Tags: java

У меня существует список объектов, например объект содержит в себе `true`/`false`. Мне нужно получить один список объектов, объекты которого хранят в себе true, а другой список, объекты которого хранят false - это я привел для примера, а так там много данных по которым мне нужно будет получать определенный список. Я не хочу проходить всю коллекцию и проверять, мне кажется это ресурсозатратным, возможно это можно реализовать как то по другому?

Comment: Как минимум один проход по всему списку придётся сделать. И это не так затратно по ресурсам, как может показаться.

Comment: вам надо разбить список на группы по определенному атрибуту у объектов?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman да

Comment: без полного просмотра списка все равно не обойтись. для группировки удобно использовать **Java 8 Stream API**. для ускорения можно запустить группировку в несколько потоков. пример использования вам дали в ответе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для отсеивания значений по какому либ опризнаку можно воспользоваться стримами в коллекциях.

```
void method(){
    ArrayList<Boolean> list = new ArrayList<>();
    /*
        Добавление значений
    */
    list
            .stream()
            .filter(value -> value)/*если true то значение не отсеивается иначе при переборе forEach этого значения не будет*/
            .forEach(value ->/*что то делаем с данными*/);
}
```